# Parse and Display xml feed of a particular site or blog in a google chrome extension!

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, rss

I've started on chrome extension development and I need to know how to fetch,parse and display rss feed of a particular blog or you can direct me to a well explained resource. 
Thanx in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jFeed](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jFeed).

```
   jQuery.getFeed({
       url: 'rss.xml',
       success: function(feed) {
           alert(feed.title);
       }
   });
```

The [Google Feed API](http://code.google.com/apis/feed/v1/devguide.html) looks pretty reliable as well, if you don't want to use jQuery for some reason.